# SAS: Converting character to numeric variable - comma as a decimal separator

Tags: sas, formatting, type-conversion, data-conversion

I'm trying to use **INPUT** function, as it is always suggested, but it seems that SAS has some problems with proper interpretation of amounts like:
2,30 
1,61 
0,00 
...and I end up with missing values. Perhaps it's caused by comma being thousands separator where SAS come from ;)

```
data temp;
    old = '1,61';
    new = input(old, 5.2);
run;
```

Why the result of above is new = **.**?

It seems that I've found some work-around - by replacing comma with a period using **TRANWRD** before INPUT function is called (*vide* code below), but it's quite ugly solution and I suppose there must be a proper one.

```
data temp;
    old = '1,61';
    new = input(tranwrd(old,',','.'), 5.2);
run;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason `new = .` in your example is because SAS does not recognize the comma as a decimal separator. See the note in the log.

> NOTE: Invalid argument to function INPUT at line 4 column 11.
>   old=1,61 new=. *ERROR*=1 *N*=1
>   NOTE: Mathematical operations could not be performed at the following places. The results of the operations have been set to
>         missing values.

[The documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001239776.htm) contains a list of various SAS informats. Based on the documentation it looks like you can use the `COMMAX` informat.

> COMMAXw.d - Writes numeric values with a period that separates every three digits and a comma that separates the decimal fraction.

The modified code looks like this:

```
data temp;
    old = '1,61';
    new = input(old,commax5.);
run;

proc print;
```

The resulting output is:

```
Obs    old      new

 1     1,61    1.61
```

If you want to keep the `new` variable in the same format you can just add the statement `format new commax5.;` to the data step.

Thanks to Tom for pointing out that SAS uses informats in the `INPUT()` function.

Comment: The `INPUT()` function uses INFORMATs, not FORMATs.  Fortunately there is an informat named `COMMAX` that your code will use. However you do NOT want to use the decimal specification on an informat.  `input(old,commax5.2)` would convert `'123'` into `1.23` since it will put assume that your input string had removed the decimal separator to save space.  So just use `input(old,commax5.)`.